# Cannot optimize the bias parameter in linear regression

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to train a very basic linear regression model to predict a linear equation Y = m*X + c

The Weight parameter is optimized to 5 but the Bias parameter is stuck at 0. Am I doing something wrong?

```
X = np.array(range(1,1000))
Y = 5 * X + 7

def forward(W, X ,b):
    return W * X + b

def getcost(Y, y):
    return np.sum((Y-y)**2) / 1000

def backward(W, b, X, Y, y, lr):
    dW = -2 * np.dot((Y-y).T, X) / 1000
    db = -2 * np.sum(Y-y) / 1000
    W -= lr * dW
    b -= lr * db
    return W, b

W = 0.0
b = 0.0

for i in range(80):
    y = forward(W, X ,b)
    cost = getcost(Y, y)
    W, b = backward(W, b, X, Y, y, lr=0.000001)
    print(int(cost), W, b)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range of X is too extensive since X and Y have a linear relationship the model can be trained on a small range of values. The learning rate is very small it will take much more time to converge since your input set is very big. If you really want to use the same data then You can normalize X.

```
X = np.array(range(1,30))
Y = 5 * X +7

# Normalize the X values
#X = (X - np.mean(X)) / np.std(X)

N = len(Y)
learning_rate = 0.001

# Initialize the model with the correct values for m and b
m, b = 0.0, 0.0
errors = []
for p in range(8000):
    hyp = m * X + b
    error = Y - hyp
    m_gradient = -(2/N) * np.sum(X * error)
    b_gradient = -(2/N) * np.sum(error)
    m = m - learning_rate * m_gradient
    b = b - learning_rate * b_gradient
    errors.append(np.mean(error ** 2))
    if p%400==0:
        print(f'm={m} b={b} ' ) 
# prediction for x = 231 , y should be 5*200+7 = 1007 
print( m*200+b)

plt.plot(errors)
#
plt.xlabel('Iteration')
plt.ylabel('Error')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Ahsan Nawaz
The only changes I made to your code are -

1. Scaled your features (for otherwise, increasing the learning_rate gave NANs)
2. Increased the learning rate
3. Increased the number of epochs

Here is your code modified -

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X = np.array(range(1,1000))

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X.reshape(-1,1))
X = scaler.transform(X.reshape(-1,1)).reshape(-1)
Y = 5 * X + 7

def forward(W, X ,b):
    return W * X + b

def getcost(Y, y):
    return np.sum((Y-y)**2) / 1000

def backward(W, b, X, Y, y, lr):
    dW = -2 * np.dot((Y-y).T, X) / 1000
    db = -2 * np.sum(Y-y) / 1000
    W -= lr * dW
    b -= lr * db
    return W, b

W = 0.0
b = 0.0

for i in range(8000):
    y = forward(W, X ,b)
    cost = getcost(Y, y)
    W, b = backward(W, b, X, Y, y, lr=0.001)
    print(int(cost), W, b)
```

Here is the final output -

```
0 4.999999437318114 6.999999212245364
```