# Getting infinity values from gradient descent

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I'm trying to implement a multivariable linear regression with gradient descent but when I try this:

```
# Starting values
w = np.ones(3) # The number of features is 3
b = float(0)

def gradient_descent():
  global w
  global b

  learning_rate = 0.0001

  for i in range(x_train.shape[0]):
    prediction = np.dot(x_train[i], w) + b
    error = x_train[i] - prediction
    for j in range(w.shape[0]):
      w[j] = w[j] - (error * x_train[i][j] * learning_rate)
    b = b - (error * learning_rate)

def train():
  for i in range(10_000):
    gradient_descent()
    print(i, ':', w, b)

train()
```

the output is

```
0 : [inf inf inf] inf
1 : [inf inf inf] inf
2 : [inf inf inf] inf
3 : [inf inf inf] inf
4 : [inf inf inf] inf
5 : [inf inf inf] inf
6 : [inf inf inf] inf
....
```

so what I did wrong?
I tried to decrease the learning rate but nothing changed

data sample:

```
total_rooms,population,households,bedrooms(target)
5612.0,1015.0,472.0,1283.0
7650.0,1129.0,463.0,1901.0
720.0,333.0,117.0,174.0
1501.0,515.0,226.0,337.0
1454.0,624.0,262.0,326.0
```

which total_rooms, population and households is x_train with shape (17000, 3)
and bedrooms is y_train with shape (17000, 1)

when I try to scale the data using `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` before splitting the data

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
train_data = scaler.fit_transform(train_data)
x_train = train_data[:, :3]
y_train = train_data[:, -1]
```

I get `nan` instead of `inf`!

note: The data works fine with scaling or not with `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression`

Comment: We have no idea what your data are. Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for the input data. I guess x_tarin is  x_train and y_train's shape is (17000, 1).

Comment: Try scaling your features - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74909615/cannot-optimize-the-bias-parameter-in-linear-regression/74910323#74910323

Comment: @desert_ranger I tried to scale the data using `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` but I get `nan` in the output instead of `inf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments: feature scaling is a good idea (scikit-learn includes [`SimpleScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), but it's pretty straightforward to subtract the mean of each column and divide by the standard deviation as well).

Also: the error term appears to be backwards, the residual is usually `prediction - true`.

```py
error = prediction - y[i]
```

Comment: when I try to scale the data using `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` or when I do `error = prediction -  y_train[I]` I get `nan` instead of `inf`

Comment: Does your data contain nan values? Have you tried this on simpler datasets? (e.g. [`make_regression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_regression.html))

Comment: Think about your gradient descent: `F(w, b) = sum_{x,y}(wx + b - y)² -> min`. Therefore `∇_w F = sum_{x,y} (wx + b - y) * x` and `∇_b F = sum_{x,y} (wx + b - y)`. There is nothing to guess - it is `prediction - y` in your case.

Comment: And for normalization you can just do `(data - mean(data)) / std(data)`. No library required.

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes I tried the data on `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` and it works

Comment: I've ran the code successfully on several datasets. Other possible culprits are your environment (e.g. if you're in a Jupyter notebook, executing cells multiple times can cause subtle bugs), or the dataset you are using.

Comment: Note also that there are several typos in the original code, such as `x_tarin` and `x_train` being used interchangeably.

Comment: I actually it worked but it work only when the learning rate is less than 0.00000001. maybe it's something about google Colab because I ran the code more than once and worked after serval times

Answer (score 1):

Without optimization or any warranty: Normalization and correctly applied gradient descent formula leads you to something like

```py
import numpy as np


def gradient_descent(x_train, y_train, w=np.ones(3), b=float(0), learning_rate=0.001):
    predictions = x_train @ w + b
    error = predictions - y_train
    w = w - learning_rate * error @ x_train
    b = b - learning_rate * sum(error)
    return w, b


def train():
    # data with last column being the target
    data = np.array(
        [
            [5612.0, 1015.0, 472.0, 1283.0],
            [7650.0, 1129.0, 463.0, 1901.0],
            [720.0, 333.0, 117.0, 174.0],
            [1501.0, 515.0, 226.0, 337.0],
            [1454.0, 624.0, 262.0, 326.0],
        ]
    )
    norm_offset = np.mean(data[:])
    norm_factor = 1 / np.std(data[:])
    data_normalized = (data - norm_offset) * norm_factor
    x_train = data_normalized[:, :-1]
    y_train = data_normalized[:, -1]

    # start values
    w = np.ones(x_train.shape[1])
    b = float(0)

    # train
    for i in range(10_000):
        w, b = gradient_descent(x_train, y_train, w, b)
        # o = offset, f = factor, w'/b' normalized parameters, w/b original parameters
        #   y' = w' * x' + b'
        #   f * (y - o) = w' * f * (x - o) + b'
        #   y = w' * (x - o) + b' / f + o
        #   y = w' * x - o * sum(w') + b' / f + o
        #   => w = w', b = b' / f + o - o * sum(w')
        b_orig = b / norm_factor + norm_offset - sum(w) * norm_offset
        ssr = np.sum((data[:, :3] @ w + b_orig - data[:, 3]) ** 2)
        print(i, ':', w, b_orig, ssr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    train()
```

```
...
9999 : [0.13503938 0.69644619 0.75400302] -386.71116671360414 71015.11748640954
```